How to return array of objects as nested field from sql query?
I'm quite new to sql so I don't quite know what is the correct approach to fix my problem.
I have two tables, events and labels that have many-to-many relations on id field. i also create junction table for them.
I want to get data from tables in following format:
it should be an array of events and each event should have labels field, which is a list of labels for this event
[
 {
  id: 'event1',
  labels: [
   { id: 'label1'},
   { id: 'label2'},
 },
 {
  id: 'event2',
  labels: [
   { id: 'label3'},
   { id: 'label4'},
 }
]

what is the best way to achieve it? should i write some subquery or should i do split the query into two separate and just combine them later?
I'm using node, drizzle and postgres
i tried drizzle query and select syntax but couldn't achieve needed result
here's my drizzle schemas
const events = pgTable('events', {
  id: uuid('id').primaryKey(),
  userId: uuid('user_id')
    .notNull()
    .references(() => authUsers.id, { onDelete: 'cascade' }),
  description: text('description').notNull(),
  dueDate: timestamp('due_date'),
  createdAt: timestamp('created_at').notNull().defaultNow(),
})

const eventsRelations = relations(events, ({ many }) => ({
  eventsToLabels: many(eventsToLabels),
}))

const labels = pgTable('labels', {
  id: uuid('id').primaryKey(),
  label: text('label').notNull(),
  description: text('description'),
  userId: uuid('user_id').references(() => authUsers.id, {
    onDelete: 'cascade',
  }),
})

const labelsRelations = relations(labels, ({ many }) => ({
  eventsToLabels: many(eventsToLabels),
}))

const eventsToLabels = pgTable(
  'event_label',
  {
    eventId: uuid('event_id')
      .notNull()
      .references(() => events.id, { onDelete: 'cascade' }),
    labelId: uuid('label_id')
      .notNull()
      .references(() => labels.id, { onDelete: 'cascade' }),
  },
  (table) => ({
    pk: primaryKey({ columns: [table.eventId, table.labelId] }),
  }),
)


Please provide the relevant section of your drizzle database schema file, as well as the code related to the problem.

my final solution

      db.select({
        id: events.id,
        labels: sql`json_agg(json_build_object('id', ${labels.id}))`,
      })
      .from(events)
      .leftJoin(eventsToLabels, eq(events.id, eventsToLabels.eventId))
      .leftJoin(labels, eq(labels.id, eventsToLabels.labelId))
      .where(eq(events.id, eventId))
      .groupBy(events.id)


The official documentation simply tells you to use Array.reduce()

You’re free to operate with results the way you want, here’s an example of mapping many-one relational data:

type User = typeof usersTable.$inferSelect;
type Pet = typeof usersTable.$inferSelect;

const rows = db
  .select({ user: users, pet: pets })
  .from(users)
  .leftJoin(pets, eq(users.id, pets.ownerId))
  .all();

const result = rows.reduce<Record<number, { user: User; pets: Pet[] }>>((acc, row) => {
  //
}, {});

// result type
const result: Record<number, { user: User; pets: Pet[] }>;

